# linux command to read RFID usb port

Tags: linux, bash, usb, cat, rfid

im try to read data from an usb RFID reader.

```
airone@airone:~$ sudo tree /dev/input
/dev/input
├── by-id
│   ├── usb-413c_3010-event-mouse -> ../event2
│   ├── usb-413c_3010-mouse -> ../mouse0
│   ├── usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event3
│   └── usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315-event-kbd -> ../event5
├── by-path
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event5
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:2:1.0-event-mouse -> ../event2
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1d.1-usb-0:2:1.0-mouse -> ../mouse0
│   └── pci-0000:00:1d.2-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event3
├── event0
├── event1
├── event2
├── event3
├── event4
├── event5
├── mice
└── mouse0

2 directories, 16 files
airone@airone:~$
```

my RIFD reader is:

**usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315-event-kbd -> ../event5**

when i put the token near the RFID i get this:

```
2 directories, 16 files
airone@airone:~$ sudo cat -v /dev/input/by-id/usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315-event-kbd 
M-1ZKX~M-m^A^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKX~M-m^A^@^A^@^K^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKX~M-m^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-7^L^B^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-7^L^B^@^A^@^K^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-7^L^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-s+^B^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-s+^B^@^A^@^K^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-s+^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1K^B^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKX1K^B^@^A^@^K^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1K^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXpj^B^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKXpj^B^@^A^@^K^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXpj^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2M-^I^B^@^D^@^D^@'^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-2M-^I^B^@^A^@^K^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2M-^I^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-rM-(^B^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-rM-(^B^@^A^@^F^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-rM-(^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1M-H^B^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKX1M-H^B^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1M-H^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXsM-g^B^@^D^@^D^@#^@^G^@M-1ZKXsM-g^B^@^A^@^G^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXsM-g^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2^F^C^@^D^@^D^@#^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-2^F^C^@^A^@^G^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2^F^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-v%^C^@^D^@^D^@#^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-v%^C^@^A^@^G^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-v%^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX0E^C^@^D^@^D^@#^@^G^@M-1ZKX0E^C^@^A^@^G^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX0E^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXqd^C^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKXqd^C^@^A^@^F^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXqd^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-;M-^C^C^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-;M-^C^C^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-;M-^C^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-qM-"^C^@^D^@^D^@%^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-qM-"^C^@^A^@ ^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-qM-"^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX0M-B^C^@^D^@^D^@%^@^G^@M-1ZKX0M-B^C^@^A^@    ^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX0M-B^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXtM-a^C^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKXtM-a^C^@^A^@^F^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXtM-a^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-1^@^D^@^D^@^D^@"^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-1^@^D^@^A^@^F^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-1^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-q^_^D^@^D^@^D^@&^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-q^_^D^@^A^@
^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-q^_^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1?^D^@^D^@^D^@&^@^G^@M-1ZKX1?^D^@^A^@
^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKX1?^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXr^^D^@^D^@^D^@(^@^G^@M-1ZKXr^^D^@^A^@^\^@^A^@^@^@M-1ZKXr^^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2}^D^@^D^@^D^@(^@^G^@M-1ZKXM-2}^D^@^A^@^\^@^@^@^@^@M-1ZKXM-2}^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@0005665859
```

how I can translate this ? its possibile ? thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: doesn't the supplier of your RFID reader publish documentation and an API for reading output from their product? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter is the em4100 (microsoft brand on the case) its too simple have you any suggestion to give me ?

Comment: Sorry, nothing else comes to mind. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Use `evdump` to interpret the raw data:
`evdump /dev/input/by-id/usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_*`

I assume you'd like to read the entire RFID code. For this, use the following Python script which is largely based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913707/5795026:

```
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes, list_devices
from select import select

keys = "X^1234567890XXXXqwertzuiopXXXXasdfghjklXXXXXyxcvbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/by-id/usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315-event-kbd")

barcode = ""
while True:
    r,w,x = select([dev], [], [])

    for event in dev.read():
        if event.type != 1 or event.value != 1:
            continue
        if event.code == 28:
            print(barcode)
            barcode = ""
            break
        barcode += keys[event.code]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already figured out how to identify the keyboard device, all you have to do is pipe your output to hexdump -- here's an example:

> $ sudo cat /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.4.4:1.0-event-kbd | hexdump

This gives the usual hexdump output:

```
0000000 7b84 61d6 0000 0000 f504 0007 0000 0000
0000010 0004 0004 0027 0007 7b84 61d6 0000 0000
0000020 f504 0007 0000 0000 0001 000b 0001 0000
0000030 7b84 61d6 0000 0000 f504 0007 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 7b84 61d6 0000 0000
0000050 1422 0008 0000 0000 0004 0004 0027 0007
```